# Jquery event bubbling when .on event is within a nested function

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-bubbling

I have this code in the body onload event:

```
$.each(["#tbl_p2", "#tbl_p5", "#tbl_ukalk"], function(index,value){
    $("tbody tr:not(:last)", value).find("input[type='text']:visible:last").on("blur", this, function(){
        $("tbody tr:last input[type='text']:first", value).focus()
    })
})
```

The mentioned tables (tbl_p2, tbl_p5 and tbl_ukalk) are all added dynamically at some point and they consists of several lines with several text inputs at each line. The intention of the code is to focus() the first input of the last line whenever the the last input of whichever line is blurred.

It works when applied through the console, but not via onload, so I know it has something to do with bubbling. I've tried to add "document" like this...

```
$.each(["#tbl_p2", "#tbl_p5", "#tbl_ukalk"], function(index,value){
    $("document tbody tr:not(:last)", value).find("input[type='text']:visible:last").on("blur", this, function(){
        $("tbody tr:last input[type='text']:first", value).focus()
    })
})
```

...to bubble far enough out, but that won't work neither in console or onload - I'm assuming beacuse "document" isn't part of the given context in $.each().

I've also tried to do `$.each(["document #tbl_p2", ...])` but that doesn't work either.

Edit: Added [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9u7EZ/) with working code. If the tables were added dynamically, it wouldn't work.

Edit II: Updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7UTBQ/) with dynamically added table, which serves to show that the event listener doesn't update to the new table element.

Edit III: 100% working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7UTBQ/4/), many thanks to @Rob Schmuecker (see accepted answer)

Comment: Seems like your code runs before the tables are added.

Comment: @AnkitJaiswal, I know that. That's where event bubbling, or rather event delegation, comes in. It should work anyway. Have a look at the last section of [this page](http://jqfundamentals.com/chapter/events).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is to do with event delegation since the tables aren't loaded by the time you've called `onload`?

Have a look here http://api.jquery.com/on/ about delegating your events.
You may have to reformat your code slightly to get it to work properly.

Or alternatively call your code only when the tables have actually been loaded into the DOM such as in the `success` callback of an ajax request or similar.

EDIT: 
Here is a correct working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7UTBQ/3/
and here is the correct working javascript

JS:

```
$(document).on("blur", "table tr:not(tr:last-child) td:last-child input[type='text']:visible", function (event) {
    console.log('blur');
    $("tr:last input[type='text']:first", $(event.target).parents('table').get(0)).focus();
});
```

Comment: Well, reformatting my code is what I need help for. I'm aware about event delegation, that's why I tried to add "document" as the first selector to make sure the event is delegated to an element which exists from the start.

Comment: @aanders77 I will try and help you if you can provide a jsfiddle.net with some dummy tables with the inputs etc in them.  You can just mock them up in the HTML section (with same class names, ID's etc) and I'll make sure they get added dynamically so we can reproduce your processflow and get you sorted.  The issue is with the order of your selectors but without something to test I'm not confident enough to get it correct with one-attempt in the comments!

Comment: here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9u7EZ/). I'm looking forward to your answer, and to see how you get the tables added dynamically in the fiddle :)

Comment: @aanders77 I have edited and provided a correct working solution.  I had to change the selectors as the `:last` selector only returns a single element as opposed to the last one in each row.

Comment: I've tried with your code but still no joy. The problem is not when adding new lines, but rather that the tables themselves are inserted dynamically. I've edited your fiddle a bit, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7UTBQ/), to add a table dynamically, and as you can see, in the new table blur doesn't take the cursor to the correct input. My guess is it would work if I reattached the event listener, but that shouldn't be necessary, should it?

Comment: @aanders77 here is what you want working on adding dynamic tables. http://jsfiddle.net/7UTBQ/3/

Comment: Beautiful! I took the liberty of updating your fiddle so that the event only applies to the specified tables http://jsfiddle.net/7UTBQ/4/

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$.each(["#tbl_p2", "#tbl_p5", "#tbl_ukalk"], function(index,value){
    $("document tbody tr:not(:last) "+value).find("input[type='text']:visible:last").on("blur", this, function(){
        $("tbody tr:last input[type='text']:first "+value).focus()
    })
})
```

Not tested by my side you can try..

Comment: need to see your fiddle you should crate it for you.